# Reproduce a raster with same cell size but different no of columns and rows

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem

I have a DEM raster of 200m resolution, the no of columns and rows are  2458 and 2845, I want to reproduce this raster in a way that the cell size remains the same i.e. 200,200 but the no of columns and rows should be below 36 (thats the requirement of my software), I have tried using the aggregate tool but it reduces the no of columns and rows but increases the cell size up to 2000.

Can anyone suggest me a tool to achieve this sort of conversion in ArcGIS  10.1?

Comment: Your original image is 2458x200 m wide which makes 491.6 km. If you must keep cell size at 200m and you can only have 36 pixels it means that result image is 36x200m wide which makes 7.2 km. You must select your area of interest and crop.